# IsBlocked information in ThreadState and TaskStatus

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

The class `System.Threading.Thread` provides a property `ThreadState` where I can see whether the thread is blocked by a lock-statement (`ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin`).

Now I switched my code to the `Task` Parallel Library. But it seems that the equivalent `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus` does not provide this information.

Is it also possible to see if a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` is currently blocked?

Comment: There is the Status property, but it is not exactly the same: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.status(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Tasks rely on cooperative concurrency rather than pre-empting each other, so there shouldn't be a lot of scenarios where you need to check whether the `Task` is blocked. May I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: It's for debugging. I added some lamps on the UI which gets red when blocked or green when running.

Comment: You should probably be using the [Concurrency Visualizer Extension for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/24b56e51-fcc2-423f-b811-f16f3fa3af7a). A `Task` object does not even necessarily correspond to a single thread (a `Task` is really just a promise to produce a value, or at least a completion status, some time in the future), but the Concurrency Visualizer provides a broad set of features that will give you a great deal of insight regarding the execution status of tasks and threads in your code.

Comment: Sounds good but i use only the VS Express version which cannot use this PlugIn.